# OS X swift send mail with attachment

Tags: swift, macos, email, cocoa

i working with swift for osx.
i have this code for sending mails:

```
let service = NSSharingService(named: NSSharingServiceNameComposeEmail)!
service.recipients = ["abc@domain.de"]
service.subject = "My Subject"
service.perform(withItems: ["My Message"])
```

but i would like attach a pdf file.
how can i realize it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this work 
[see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42715256/swift-3-send-mail-with-attachment)

```
let email = "your email here"
let path = "/Users/myname/Desktop/report.txt"
let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

let sharingService = NSSharingService(named: NSSharingServiceNameComposeEmail)
sharingService?.recipients = [email] //could be more than one
sharingService?.subject = "subject"
let items: [Any] = ["see attachment", fileURL] //the interesting part, here you add body text as well as URL for the document you'd like to share

sharingService?.perform(withItems: items)
```

Comment: how can we get the completion status of `sharingService?.perform` ?